# How to make the div content scroll automatically in this case

Tags: jquery

I am displaying news through RSS Feeds in my website this way

```
<div id="divRss"></div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#divRss').FeedEk(
    {
        FeedUrl: 'http://www.moneycontrol.com/rss/results.xml'
    });
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    $('#example, .itemTitle a').css("color", getHex(r, g, b));
    $('#example').click(function()
    {
        $('.itemTitle a').css("color", getHex(r, g, b));
    });

    function intToHex(n)
    {
        n = n.toString(16);
        if (n.length < 2) n = "0" + n;
        return n;
    }

    function getHex(r, g, b)
    {
        return '#' + intToHex(r) + intToHex(g) + intToHex(b);
    }
});
```

All this is working fine , and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nqkH4/459/

But is it possible to scroll the div automatically from top to bottom as shown in this  fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/30d4h3s6/

Could you please let me know how to achive this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<marquee direction="up" height="200" truespeed="1" scrolldelay="50" scrollamount="1" onmouseout="this.start()" onmouseover="this.stop()"><div>Your Content</div></marquee>
```

Comment: You need to define your answer for the better judgement.

Comment: Thanks a lot . it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about using marquee tag to do this.

```
<marquee>
    <div>Your Content</div>
</marquee>
```

And here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqkH4/459/) with Marquee.

> Note that `Marquee`s are non-standard, but still supported in all the major browsers.